# Xamarin.Forms: Setting Style in a Class

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this XAML which I am trying to convert to a custom control:

This Works:

```
 <Label Style="{StaticResource MaterialFontIcon}" />
```

I wrote this below, but the style doesn't come through:

```
public class MaterialLabel: Label
{
    public MaterialLabel()
    {
        this.Style = {How to access a app.xaml defined style}???;
    }
```

Referenced:

```
 <me:MaterialLabel Style="{StaticResource MaterialFontIcon}" />
```

Comment: Style and StyleClass are two different things, right?

Comment: You can do `this.Style = Application.Current.Resources["MaterialFontIcon"] as Style;` if it's in your App.xaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to do `this.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["MaterialFontIcon"];` . Microsoft shows this in their docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/application#creating-a-global-style-in-c). Make sure to browse around the docs, there is some good info in there.

Answer (score -1):

From Rick

```
 this.Style = Application.Current.Resources["MaterialFontIcon"] as Style;
```